# included dbconfig.php file failes when using a direct path instead of relative path

Tags: php, path, include

I am developing an app and using a sub folder as a test domain.

```
http://mywebsite/testing-folder
```

my dbconfig is located at:

```
http://mywebsite/testing-folder/lib/dbconfig.php
```

if I include the file from:
 `http://mywebsite/testing-folder/userarea/profile`

with a relative path it is fine. If I include it with a direct path it throws an error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...

$root = 'http://mywebsite/testing-folder/';
include '../../lib/dbconfig.php'; // This works
include $root.'lib/dbconfig.php'; // This does not
```

any clue as to why?

Comment: Please read this and you'll find your answer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#52342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include file over HTTP. That is not right, you should include files with passing your local filesystem path to `include` or `require`.

Your root should probably look like so:

```
$root = '/var/www/mywebsite/testing-folder/';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the URL, you have to use a file system path. So instead of

```
$root = 'http://mywebsite/testing-folder/';
```

something like

```
$root = '/var/www/whatever/';
```

should be used. When you include php over http, your webserver will already interpret the code and return whatever you output there (like `echo "hello world";`). If your files just contains configuration, the output is likely to be empty.

Comment: This one was answered first though! This says 35 mins ago whereas the accepted answer says 38 mins ago.